# How to add Meta Tags dynamically to pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, header, meta-tags

I have a website with product pages that are created dynamically depending on the itemws in my database. The site works fine with no errors.  I now would like to add Meta Tags to the header.

When the pages are created I would like to dynamically/programmically set the meta tags for that page - Keywords, etc.

How can I add them using VB.Net in Visual Studio 2008.  I am using a masterpage for the overall layout if that affects anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2006/03/25/18992.aspx  I think its exactly what you want
ex.

```
// Render: <meta name="date" content="2006-03-25" scheme="YYYY-MM-DD" />
meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "date";
meta.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
meta.Scheme = "YYYY-MM-DD";
this.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Comment: To change Name to property for the meta tag, you can do the following:


Dim meta As HtmlMeta = New HtmlMeta()
meta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image")
meta.Content = "http://www.domain.com/image.jpg"
Me.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta)

Comment: `meta name="keywords"`  `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"`   `meta name="twitter:title"` `meta property="og:site_name"` ?